# Optaplanner: Vehicle Routing – order of precedence while visiting cities

Tags: optaplanner

Suppose that you have a car that is required to visit cities A, B, C, D and E in the shortest possible time or distance. But there is order of precedence in which these cities can be visited. For e.g., B must be visited first before you visit “A,” and “E” must be visited first before you can visit “C.” So all of the following solutions are valid:
Car -> B, D, E, A, C
Or
Car -> D, E, B, A, C
Or
Car -> E, B, A, D, C
Following routes will be invalid:
Car -> A, B, D, E, C (Constraint violated since B must be visited first before you can visit A)
Or 
Car -> B, D, A, C, E (Constraint violated since E must be visited first before you can visit C)

In Optaplanner, is there any way to enforce such constraints? I think this has to be done while forming a chain. The default chain might have to be manually revisited to enforce such a constraint. But I don’t know how. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.
Vikas

Comment: Take a look at OptaPlanner 6.3's release notes, specifically: http://www.optaplanner.org/download/releaseNotes/releaseNotes6.3.html#_variablelisteners_now_trigger_in_a_smart_order and also http://docs.jboss.org/optaplanner/release/6.3.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html/ch04.html#variableListenerTriggeringOrder

Answer (score 1):

Introduce a shadow variable that keeps the `chainIndex` in a chain of a vehicles.

For example: Vehicle A starts in Brussels then goes to Paris then to London. Vehicle B starts in Brussels then goes to Berlin and then to Prague. Then it works like this:

- Paris's anchor is A and its `chainIndex` is 1.
- London's anchor is A and its `chainIndex` is 2.
- Berlin's anchor is B and its `chainIndex` is 1.
- Prague's anchor is B and its `chainIndex` is 2.

Adding your constraint by using that `chainIndex` and the anchor is then trivial.